# How to click a checkbox using selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

```
<div id="yui_3_16_0_1_1399697074576_1339" class="cbox " role="gridcell">
<input id="yui_3_16_0_1_1399697074576_1338" type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" 89513626107905="" aria-label="Message " title="Select this email">
<span id="yui_3_16_0_1_1399697074576_1340" class="icon"></span>
</div>`
```

The above HTML is from firebug.

I want to click the checkbox, its ID is `id="yui_3_16_0_1_1399697074576_1338"` from above. I tried using `by.id` and `by.path`, however neither of them work.
The following is what I tried:

```
By.id("yui_3_16_0_1_1399697074576_1338")
By.xpath("//input[@id='yui_3_16_0_1_1399697074576_1339'
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: If you tried By.id | By.xpath with findElement and neither of them work than the selected id may be generated.

Comment: Sounds like the ID is dynamically generated.

Comment: Since the ID looks like it's dynamically generated you need to look for some distinct ids, classes or elements, such that you can find from them the div with the input. This can then be done for example with positional selector `<some specific selector higher up>/div[1]/input[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

if the id is static :

```
 string checkboxXPath = "//input[contains(@id, 'yui_3_16_0_1_1399697074576_1338')]"
```

for Dynamic Tags value:

```
           string checkboxXPath = "//input[contains(@type,'checkbox') and                       
          contains(@title,'Select this email')]"

IWebElement elementToClick = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(checkboxXPath));
elementToClick.Click();
```

Comment: the ID value change everytime, so i cant use find ID. i need another way to do this

Comment: thank you loknath, thats what i did too, using 'contains(@title, 'Select this email'); i cant vote since i am new here

Answer (score 1):

You **NEVER** want to match on an ID like that.  What I'd recommend, is matching on something a little more "unique".

Try:

```
By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox'][title='Select this email']")
```

This selector above will match your `<input/>` perfectly.  And, it's not coupled with the Yahoo UI so if you or your developers ever change software, it will account for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the element using the id and make a click. It is similar to button click

```
driver.findElement(By.id("yui_3_16_0_1_1399697074576_1338")).click();
```